# "Color cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

```
import java.awp.*;
public class Reindeer
{
  private String name;
  private boolean canFly;
  private Color noseColor;
  private int antlers;

  public Reindeer()
  {
  }
  public Reindeer(String nameIn, boolean canFlyIn, Color noseColorIn, int antlersIn)
  {
    name = nameIn;
    canFly = canFlyIn;
    noseColor = noseColorIn;
    antlers = antlersIn;
  }
  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
  public boolean getCanFly()
  {
    return canFly;
  }
  public Color getNoseColor()
  {
    return noseColor;
  }
  public int getAntlers()
  {
    return antlers;
  }
  public void setCanFly(boolean canFlyIn)
  {
    canFly = canFlyIn;
  }
  public void setNoseColor(Color noseColorIn)
  {
    noseColor = noseColorIn;
  }
  public void setAntlers(int antlersIn)
  {
    antlers = antlersIn;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "The Reindeer's name is " + name + " and it has a " + noseColor + " nose.";
  }
}
```

Unsure of what to do here, would be great if I had some help. I know I have to import something but I had forgotten what it is and I believe it is something along the lines of 'import java.awp.*;' Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the docs?

Comment: Can i have an explanation of this..?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for "awp" to see where `Color` is defined?

Comment: No. That would most likely be where my issue was.

Comment: Ok, then if you're sure `Color` is part of "awp", then use Google to find the documentation for the library, and find where `Color` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a typo. The java.* top-level packages are restricted, so there are only so many and they are all known. `awp` is probably supposed to be `awt`.